# "restore purchases" button for non-consumables required?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've read people say that their apps got rejected from not having a "restore purchases" button so that when migrating to a new device, the user can transfer/activate their previous purchases.

My question is, is a button for this behavior really necessary?  I would like to just have a UserDefaults setting, something like "transferred" with a default value of false, and when the app launches, if that value is false, it will make the call to apple's servers to restore everything and then set the flag to true--- so the user doesn't have to do anything, it's just automatic, and I don't have to put an unnecessary button in my UI.

Is this an acceptable thing to do or will I really get rejected just from not having a button?

Comment: People can only speculate on it, since at the end of the day it's up to Apple to accept or reject and god knows they are not consistent. One app with this logic could get accepted and another could get rejected. So in my opinion, put the button up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Apple app Policies and not about programming.

Comment: You need a restore button.

Comment: The `NSUserDefault` value will be erased if the application is deleted. Then what do you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they surely ask for the restore button. I too face this issue before.

The `Apple` defines the user must know the thing what is going on. Because the user if already purchased , then it ask again for purchase they really should not do, right! So, for the clarification only apple reject this.

In my app I just give the link "Already purchased?" below purchase. Then I reply to apple "Already purchased?" link have the restore functionality. Then only they accept my app from review.
Thanks!